# dags folder permission in Airflow with network_mode: host

Tags: docker-compose, airflow

I'm running Ariflow with docker compose and had to switch to `network_mode: host` for compatibility with some internal services.
Now I'm facing an issue of each time I'm starting my containers with `docker compose up` permissions of `dags` folder are changed and it's owned by `5000:root` user.

How can I prevent this?

some sample lines from docker-compose.yaml:

```
  ...
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    ...
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
       - "./logs:/opt/airflow/logs"
       - "./dags:/opt/airflow/dags"
   ...
```

Comment: Just wondering, [did you provide environment variable AIRFLOW_UID](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user) with host user uid into the containers?

Comment: @AndreyAnshin yes, I've tested internal UID and default values but in both cases permissions are changed